# Oracle Apex and Twilio API

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I am trying to have my application use Twilio's SMS API to send a text message to a user's phone when they complete a certain action. What is the general process for doing this in Oracle Apex?

Answer (score 1):

These are just two of a few posts out there on sending SMS from the database.

https://www.jmjcloud.com/blog/sms-messaging-from-oracle-erp-with-ords-and-twillio
https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2016/08/send-sms-mms-and-voice-messages-from-oracle-plsql/

It usually requires something along the lines of

- signing up for service
- installing a PL/SQL package
- enabling database ACL for the relevant host
- invoking some PL/SQL to send the SMS